# refresh ajax datatable after ajax success

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable, datatables

I use DataTable. I send data to datatable onclick in json file. The problem is When I use `$('.datatable-ajax-source table').dataTable().fnDestroy();` I loose the filter, row and pagination. I get just the table like below:

[image]

This my fuction javascript:

```
$('#ButtonPostJson').on('click', function() {           
    var forsearch = $("#searchItem").val();
    $.ajax({
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        type: 'post',
        url: 'path.json',
        dataType: "json",
        success: function(data) {
            $.each(data, function(i, data) {
                var body = "<tr>";
                body += "<td>" + data.name + "</td>";
                body += "</tr>";
            $('.datatable-ajax-source table').append(body);
        });

        /*DataTables instantiation.*/
        $('.datatable-ajax-source table').dataTable().fnDestroy();
    },
    error: function() {
        alert('Fail!');
    }
});
});
```

And when I replace `$('.datatable-ajax-source table').dataTable().fnDestroy();`
with `$('.datatable-ajax-source table').dataTable();` I get this table who I want

[image]

But when I want to search for a new term the old data is still there,I have to refrech the page manually for doing a new search. How can I refresh or update my datatable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[This link Refreshing data in jQuery DataTables](http://www.meadow.se/wordpress/refreshing-data-in-jquery-datatables/)
is verry helpfful ,I inspire from it to resolve my problem .

Answer (score 1):

You're missing the best parts of dataTables using it in this manner. Don't build your HTML manually.... use the [.rows.add()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add()) (and related) functions to redraw your table as needed.

Try this:

https://jsfiddle.net/xgpgLydb/

```
var tbl = $('#example').DataTable({
    columns: [{
    data: 'Prop1',
    title: 'Example Prop'
  },{
    data: 'Prop2',
    title: 'Example Prop 2'
  }]
});

var req = $.ajax({
    url: '/echo/json/',
    method: 'post',
    data: {
        json: JSON.stringify([{
            Prop1: 'Foo',
          Prop2: 'Bar'
        },{
            Prop1: 'Fred',
          Prop2: 'Flinstone'
        }]),
        delay: 1
    }
});

req.done(function(response) {
    tbl.rows().remove().draw();
    tbl.rows.add(response).draw();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using fnStandingRedraw to refresh the server side data and it works like a charm (unfortunately its deprecated though). You can use https://datatables.net/plug-ins/api/fnStandingRedraw

```
var ajaxSourceDataTable;

//define datatable
ajaxSourceDataTable = $('.datatable-ajax-source table').dataTable() 

//use this code to redraw/refresh datatable
ajaxSourceDataTable.fnStandingRedraw();
```